# += returns null despite values

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

Why am I returning `null` in this test when everything has a value? I can't put it more simply, but it's driving me crazy.

[image: Log]

Here's the (simplified) Apex code:

```
public class CalculatorTest {
    static testMethod void validateCalculator() {
        Decimal annualSavings, cumulativeSavings = 0;

        annualSavings = 1014.3...;

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            annualSavings *= 1.1;

            System.debug('annualSavings: ' + annualSavings);
            System.debug('cumulativeSavings: ' + cumulativeSavings);

            cumulativeSavings += annualSavings; // this returns an error, but you can see in the log the value is null

        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It makes perfect sense to me.

**EDIT**

I know it's in the wrong order above. If I switch the two bottom lines I get no `cumulativeSavings` output and this error:

[image: Null object]

**EXPANDED CODE**

```
@isTest
public class CalculatorTest {
    static testMethod void validateCalculator() {
        Decimal annualCostWonew, annualSavings, cumulativeSavings, newCost,
                oldCostAfternew, yearOneSavings, yearOneSavingsMo = 0;

        Decimal annualCost          = 4000;
        Decimal annualUsage         = 15000;
        Decimal newRate             = 0.210;
        Decimal systemDeclineRate   = 0.7 / 100;
        Decimal systemProduction    = 16000;
        Decimal oldInflation        = 8.0120 / 100;
        Decimal oldRate             = 0;

        oldRate = (oldRate == 0) ? ((annualCost / annualUsage) + annualCost / annualUsage * oldInflation) : oldRate;

        Lead l = new Lead(LastName = 'Smith', Company = 'Smith Co',
                          Annual_Cost__c = annualCost,
                          Annual_Usage__c = annualUsage,
                          New_Rate__c = newRate,
                          System_Decline_Rate__c = systemDeclineRate,
                          Old_Inflation__c = oldInflation,
                          System_Production__c = systemProduction);
        insert l;

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                systemProduction    *= (1 - systemDeclineRate);
                oldRate             *= (1 + oldInflation);
            }

            oldUseAfternew      = annualUsage - systemProduction;
            annualCostWonew     = annualUsage * oldRate;
            oldCostAfternew     = oldUseAfternew * oldRate;
            newCost             = systemProduction * newRate;
            annualSavings       = annualCostWonew - (oldCostAfternew + newCost);

            System.debug('oldUseAfternew: ' + oldUseAfternew);
            System.debug('annualCostWonew: ' + annualCostWonew);
            System.debug('oldCostAfternew: ' + oldCostAfternew);
            System.debug('newCost: ' + newCost);
            System.debug('annualSavings: ' + annualSavings);

            cumulativeSavings += annualSavings;
            System.debug('cumulativeSavings: ' + cumulativeSavings);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the declaration and initialization of the variables.

Try the following:

```
Decimal cumulativeSavings, oldUseAfternew = 0;

System.debug('oldUseAfternew: ' + oldUseAfternew);
System.assertEquals(0, oldUseAfternew);

System.debug('cumulativeSavings: ' + cumulativeSavings);
System.assertEquals(0, cumulativeSavings, 'cumulativeSavings should be initialized');
```

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: cumulativeSavings should be initialized: Expected: 0, Actual: null

Only the last variable gets assigned the initial value of `0`. Any other proceeding variables on the same line will be null.

Comment: nice -- you are three minutes smarter :-)

Comment: "Missed it by that much".
 +1 for you for the Apex doc reference with the correct way to handle multiple variable initialization.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is in the declaration statement and initialization of variables. Let's look at an example:

```
Decimal foo, bar = 0;
system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'foo='+foo+' bar='+bar);
```

Results in:

```
17:06:29:108 USER_DEBUG [2]|INFO|foo=null bar=0
```

and

```
Decimal foo = 0, bar;
system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'foo='+foo+' bar='+bar);
```

Results in:

```
17:14:16:025 USER_DEBUG [2]|INFO|foo=0 bar=null
```

In your code, the assignment of `0` applies only to the last variable in the list.

In the example from the [Apex Developer doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm), this is how Apex supports multiple initialized declarations on the same statement:

```
Integer i = 0, j, k = 1;
```

Comment: Ah! Thank-you! If you can't tell I'm new to Apex. :)

Comment: you should have given Daniel's answer as the solution - he pegged it first

Comment: Fair enough, will do.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me in an Execute Anonymous window.

This is my slightly modified code to get it working:

```
public void validateCalculator() {
    Decimal annualSavings, cumulativeSavings = 0;

    annualSavings = 1014.3;

    for (Integer i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        annualSavings *= 1.1;

        System.debug('annualSavings: ' + annualSavings);
        System.debug('cumulativeSavings: ' + cumulativeSavings);

        cumulativeSavings += annualSavings; // this returns an error, but you can see in the log the value is null

    }
}

validateCalculator();
```

Perhaps as part of you simplification you've made an error?

Comment: I'll expand the code. :)